# Using a loop to define multiple JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a page with tag buttons that can show/hide elements according with their tag.
This is my first version without loops:

https://jsfiddle.net/Pokipsy/uu7y3x2x/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showall").click(function(){
        $(".item").show();
        $(".filter").text("All elements")
    });
    $(".show.a").click(function(){
      $(".item").hide();
        $(".item.a").show();
        $(".filter").text("Tag: a")
    });
    $(".show.b").click(function(){
      $(".item").hide();
        $(".item.b").show();
        $(".filter").text("Tag: b")
    });
    $(".show.c").click(function(){
      $(".item").hide();
        $(".item.c").show();
        $(".filter").text("Tag: c")
    });
});
```

```css
.clickable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li class="clickable showall">all</li>
<li class="clickable show a">a</li>
<li class="clickable show b">b</li>
<li class="clickable show c">c</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="filter">
All elements
</h3>
<ul>
<li class="a item">first a</li>
<li class="b item">second b</li>
<li class="a b item">third a b</li>
<li class="c item ">fourth c</li>
<li class="c b item">fifth c b</li>
</ul>
```

It works but this strategy would produce a very long code if the tags are too many so I tried to use loops to make a shorter code that works with an array of tags:

https://jsfiddle.net/Pokipsy/f9uqetnn/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showall").click(function(){
        $(".item").show();
        $(".filter").text("All elements")
    });
    var tags = [".a",".b",".c"]; 
    
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    x=tags[i];
    $(".show".concat(x)).click(function(){
      $(".item").hide();
        $(".item".concat(x)).show();
        $(".filter").text("Tag: ".concat(x))
      });
    }
});
```

```css
.clickable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li class="clickable showall">all</li>
<li class="clickable show a">a</li>
<li class="clickable show b">b</li>
<li class="clickable show c">c</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="filter">
All elements
</h3>
<ul>
<li class="a item">first a</li>
<li class="b item">second b</li>
<li class="a b item">third a b</li>
<li class="c item ">fourth c</li>
<li class="c b item">fifth c b</li>
</ul>
```

but it doesn't work: apparently it always recognise a click to the last element of the array even if I clicked the first. Is there a problem with jQuery that I am unable to see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 3):

Variable `x` inside the `for` loop is overridden in each iteration so you need to lock in inside another closure. Also, I don't know what `concat()` was supposed to do, I've never seen it used with string. Just use `+` in JavaScript :).

See your update demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eddd36ma/1/

```
for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    (function(x) {
        $(".show" + x).click(function() {
            $(".item").hide();
            $(".item" + x).show();
            $(".filter").text("Tag: " + x)
        });
    })(tags[i]);
}
```

Btw, there's also [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) that takes a function as an argument, so it'd even easier to use that than `for` because the `tag` variable is scoped in each iteration:

```
tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    $(".show" + tag).click(function() {
        $(".item").hide();
        $(".item" + tag).show();
        $(".filter").text("Tag: " + tag)
    });
});
```

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eddd36ma/3/

Comment: Concat will combine two or more arrays. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

1- Instead of `showall` class use `show` instead and make click event for all `li.show`

2- make array of classes name you have

3- loop through array and break if class founded

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ClassesArray = ["a" , "b" , "c"];
    $("li.show").click(function(){
        for ( var i = 0; i < ClassesArray.length; i++ ){
            if ( $(this).hasClass( ClassesArray[i] ) ){
              $(".item").hide();
              $(".item."+ClassesArray[i]).show();
              $(".filter").text("Tag: "+ ClassesArray[i]);
              break;
            }else{
              $(".item").show();
              $(".filter").text("All elements");
            }
        } 
    });
});
```

```css
.clickable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li class="clickable show">all</li>
<li class="clickable show a">a</li>
<li class="clickable show b">b</li>
<li class="clickable show c">c</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="filter">
All elements
</h3>
<ul>
<li class="a item">first a</li>
<li class="b item">second b</li>
<li class="a b item">third a b</li>
<li class="c item ">fourth c</li>
<li class="c b item">fifth c b</li>
</ul>
```

> Note: With this code you can add another classes as you want `var ClassesArray = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , ....];` and the
>   code will work fine .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with jQuery, the problem is with logics and `for` loop. As OP noticed the click handler always use the last element which is not surprising. By the moment of click the loop is finished and `x` has the last element value. Right way to solve it is to wrap `x=tags[i]` inside a function. Something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showall").click(function(){
        $(".item").show();
        $(".filter").text("All elements")
    });
    var tags = [".a",".b",".c"]; 
    
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //x=tags[i];
    (function(x){
    $(".show".concat(x)).click(function(){
      $(".item").hide();
        $(".item".concat(x)).show();
        $(".filter").text("Tag: ".concat(x))
      });
    }(tags[i]));
    }
});
```

```css
.clickable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li class="clickable showall">all</li>
<li class="clickable show a">a</li>
<li class="clickable show b">b</li>
<li class="clickable show c">c</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="filter">
All elements
</h3>
<ul>
<li class="a item">first a</li>
<li class="b item">second b</li>
<li class="a b item">third a b</li>
<li class="c item ">fourth c</li>
<li class="c b item">fifth c b</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it this way too

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="clickableParent">
  <li data-tag="selectAll" class="clickable">all</li>
  <li data-tag="a" class="clickable">a</li>
  <li data-tag="b" class="clickable">b</li>
  <li data-tag="c" class="clickable">c</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="filter">
All elements
</h3>
<ul class="filterItemsParent">
  <li class="a item">first a</li>
  <li class="b item">second b</li>
  <li class="a b item">third a b</li>
  <li class="c item ">fourth c</li>
  <li class="c b item">fifth c b</li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var filterItemsParent = $(".filterItemsParent");
    var clickableParent = $(".clickableParent");
    var filter = $(".filter");


  clickableParent.on("click", ".clickable", function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var tag = self.data("tag");
    filter.text("Tag: " +  tag);
    tag = (tag !== "selectAll")? "." + tag : ".item";  
    filterItemsParent.children().hide().end()
        .children(tag).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

DEMO at [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uu7y3x2x/10/)!